# Reading of values from excel while cell having formula. Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I need to read excel as calculated value when cell of excel contains formula.

> Example: "=+VLOOKUP(A3,#REF!,2,0)", "=966+955+988+818+700+660+573"

Problem: PHPExecel reads formula in result and i want calculated values from excel.

Please help and see link for my [code](https://ibb.co/f3hgCw).

I'm using PHPExcel-1.8
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Classes

Im getting error as
https://ibb.co/cHb2Kb

```
if(file_exists($file_path)){
    //load the excel library
    $CI->load->library('excel');
    //read file from path
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path);
    //get only the Cell Collection
    $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
    //extract to a PHP readable array format
    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
        if(strstr($data_value,'=')==true){
           // $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCalculatedValue($cell)->getValue();
        }
        //header will/should be in row 1 only. of course this can be modified to suit your need.
        if ($row == 1) {
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        } else {
            $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
    }
    //send the data in an array format
    $data['header'] = $header;
    $data['values'] = $arr_data;
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Please add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Post your code into your question. Don't like to outside sources, and _definitely_ don't post your code as an image.

Comment: @GyandeepSharma im trying to read excel sheet using PHPExcel and codeigniter. the excel sheet contains formulas. when excel read it showing me formula in cell **Not Calculated Value**. and i need calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the ***cell's*** `getCalculatedValue()` method for cells containing formulae rather than simply `getValue()`; or trying to call `getCalculatedValue()` against the worksheet.

This is described in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate).....

it's as simple as

```
$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getCalculatedValue();
```

not anything even remotely like

```
$data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCalculatedValue($cell)->getValue();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but it only work for SUM Not for VLOOKUP. showing #REF! for vlookup formula

Comment: Well the range argument for VLOOKUP is `#REF!` in the formula that you've posted, so it will give `#REF!`

Comment: so what is the solution to get calculated value instead of #REF!